# How to convert flat raw disk image to vmdk for virtualbox or vmplayer?

Tags: image, vmware, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I have some old images of old Linux filesystems in flat file format. they can be used by [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/), but I need to run them with [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Virtual Box cannot use images in this format, so I need to convert these images from flat file to .vmdk file format. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Potentially useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual

Comment: A word of caution when using ```qemu-img``` to convert images for use with VMWare Fusion - Fusion doesn't like disks that aren't sized exactly to the megabyte. If you have such a image make sure you resize to the nearest megabyte first then convert it to vmdk format. Not doing so will result in a vmdk that can be attached to a VM at install time but any attempts to add it to a VM at a later point will result in the Apply button not working.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I was struggling to figure out why the `Apply` button wasn't working. It took me a few minutes to figure out how to increase the file size to the nearest megabyte. Here's how I did it. My file needed to be expanded by 600 kilobytes. This command did the work `dd if=/dev/zero count=600 bs=1k >> image.dd`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First, install QEMU. On Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu, run:

```sh
$ apt-get install qemu
```

Then run the following command:

```sh
$ qemu-img convert -O vmdk imagefile.dd vmdkname.vmdk
```

I’m assuming a flat disk image is a `dd`-style image. The convert operation also handles numerous other formats.

For more information about the `qemu-img` command, see the output of

```sh
$ qemu-img -h
```

Comment: Should it be disk image or partition image could be used as well ?

Comment: It's sufficient to install qemu-utils (apt-get install qemu-utils). This solution works nice (albeit a little bit slowish..)

Comment: I created a bash script to automated the process - see my answer
@krosenvold - thanx this worked great

Comment: Redhat / Fedora
`sudo dnf install qemu`
`qemu-img convert -O vmdk imagefile.dd vmdkname.vmdk -p` **p** is for progress: `(3.03/100%)`

Answer (score 102):

Since the question mentions VirtualBox, this one works currently:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw imagefile.dd vmdkname.vmdk --format VMDK
```

Run it without arguments for a few interesting details (notably the `--variant` flag):

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw
```

Comment: IMHO this is a more clean solution since it only needs Vbox's tools, and vbox is supposed to be already there.

Comment: +1 and VBoxManage can also be used to convert the other way (virtual-image to raw) `VBoxManage clonehd --format raw vmdiskimage.vmdk imagefile.dd`

Comment: +1 because using virtual box tools is more likely to make it work with virtual box (in case there are any oddities about the way it does things)

Comment: For anyone browsing for an explicit answer this also works with .img files:  `vboxmanage convertdd w1.img w1.vdi`

Comment: But is it also possible to do this without copying the whole file? So, just to somehow create an additional vmdk-metafile, that references the raw dd-image.

Comment: There is `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "my_raw_disk.vmdk" -rawdisk "/dev/sda42"` but I really don't know if it can point to a file instead of a block device.

Comment: this solution is cross platform - win/osx/linux.

Answer (score 10):

To answer TJJ: **But is it also possible to do this without copying the whole file?** So, just to somehow create an additional vmdk-metafile, that references the raw dd-image.

**Yes**, it's possible. Here's how to use a flat disk image in VirtualBox:

First you create an image with dd in the usual way:

```
dd bs=512 count=60000 if=/dev/zero of=usbdrv.img
```

Then you can create a file for VirtualBox that references this image:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "usbdrv.vmdk" -rawdisk "usbdrv.img"
```

You can use this image in VirtualBox as is, but depending on the guest OS it might not be visible immediately. For example, I experimented on using this method with a Windows guest OS and I had to do the following to give it a drive letter:

- Go to the Control Panel.
- Go to Administrative Tools.
- Go to Computer Management.
- Go to Storage\Disk Management in the left side panel.
- You'll see your disk here. Create a partition on it and format it. Use FAT for small volumes, FAT32 or NTFS for large volumes.

You might want to access your files on Linux. First dismount it from the guest OS to be sure and remove it from the virtual machine. Now we need to create a virtual device that references the partition.

```
sfdisk -d usbdrv.img
```

Response:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0xd367a714
device: usbdrv.img
unit: sectors

usbdrv.img1 : start=          63, size=       48132, type=4
```

Take note of the start position of the partition: 63. In the command below I used loop4 because it was the first available loop device in my case.

```
sudo losetup -o $((63*512)) loop4 usbdrv.img
mkdir usbdrv
sudo mount /dev/loop4 usbdrv
ls usbdrv -l
```

Response:

```
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Apr  5 17:13 'Test file.txt'
```

Yay!

Answer (score 6):

On windows, use https://github.com/Zapotek/raw2vmdk to convert raw files created by dd or winhex to vmdk. raw2vmdk v0.1.3.2 has a bug - once the vmdk file is created, edit the vmdk file and fix the path to the raw file (in my case instead of D:\Temp\flash_16gb.raw (created by winhex) the generated path was D:Tempflash_16gb.raw). Then, open it in a vmware virtual machine version 6.5-7 (5.1 was refusing to attach the vmdk harddrive). howgh!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using Starwind V2V Converter, you can get it from here - http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter. It also supports IMG disk format and performs sector-by sector conversion between IMG, VMDK or VHD into and from any of them without making any changes to source image. This tool is free :)

Comment: I tried this "StarWind V2V Image Converter" to covert a `dd` created raw image to VHD. But after selecting the source image i just get "Internal error (32) [32]".
Also before downloading you have to fill out a form and provide your email address.
Can't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

krosenvold's answer inspired the following script which does the following:

- get the dd dump via ssh from a remote server (as gz file)
- unzip the dump
- convert it to vmware

the script is restartable and checks the existence of the intermediate files. It also uses pv and qemu-img -p to show the progress of each step.

In my environment 2 x Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the steps took:

- 3 hours to get a 47 GByte disk dump of a 60 GByte partition
- 20 minutes to unpack to a 60 GByte dd file
- 45 minutes to create the vmware file

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# get a dd disk dump and convert it to vmware
#  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454899/how-to-convert-flat-raw-disk-image-to-vmdk-for-virtualbox-or-vmplayer
#  Author: wf  2014-10-1919

#
# get a dd dump from the given host's given disk and create a compressed
#   image at the given target 
#
#  1: host e.g. somehost.somedomain
#  2: disk e.g. sda
#  3: target e.g. image.gz
#
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-use-ssh-to-make-a-dd-copy-of-disk-a-from-host-b-and-save-on-disk-b
getdump() {
  local l_host="$1"
  local l_disk="$2"
  local l_target="$3"
  echo "getting disk dump of $l_disk from $l_host"
  ssh $l_host sudo fdisk -l  | egrep "^/dev/$l_disk"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "device $l_disk does not exist on host $l_host" 1>&2
    exit 1
  else
    if [ ! -f $l_target ]
    then
      ssh $l_host "sudo dd if=/dev/$disk bs=1M | gzip -1 -" | pv | dd of=$l_target
    else
      echo "$l_target already exists"
    fi
  fi
}

#
# optionally install command from package if it is not available yet
# 1: command
# 2: package
#
opt_install() {
  l_command="$1"
  l_package="$2"
  echo "checking that $l_command from package $l_package  is installed ..."
  which $l_command
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "installing $l_package to make $l_command available ..."
    sudo apt-get install $l_package 
  fi
}

#
# convert the given image to vmware
#  1: the dd dump image
#  2: the vmware image file to convert to
#
vmware_convert() {
  local l_ddimage="$1"
  local l_vmwareimage="$2"
  echo "converting dd image $l_image to vmware $l_vmwareimage"
  #  convert to VMware disk format showing progess
  # see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/qemu-img.1.html
  qemu-img convert -p -O vmdk "$l_ddimage" "$l_vmwareimage"
}

#
# show usage
#
usage() {
  echo "usage: $0 host device"
  echo "      host: the host to get the disk dump from e.g. frodo.lotr.org"  
  echo "            you need ssh and sudo privileges on that host"
  echo "
  echo "    device: the disk to dump from e.g. sda"
  echo ""
  echo "  examples:
  echo "       $0 frodo.lotr.org sda"
  echo "       $0 gandalf.lotr.org sdb"
  echo ""
  echo "  the needed packages pv and qemu-utils will be installed if not available"
  echo "  you need local sudo rights for this to work"
  exit 1
}

# check arguments
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  usage
fi

# get the command line parameters
host="$1"
disk="$2"

# calculate the names of the image files
ts=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
# prefix of all images
#   .gz the zipped dd
#   .dd the disk dump file
#   .vmware - the vmware disk file
image="${host}_${disk}_image_$ts"

echo "$0 $host/$disk ->  $image"

# first check/install necessary packages
opt_install qemu-img qemu-utils
opt_install pv pv

# check if dd files was already loaded
#  we don't want to start this tedious process twice if avoidable
if [ ! -f $image.gz ]
then
  getdump $host $disk $image.gz
else
  echo "$image.gz already downloaded"
fi

# check if the dd file was already uncompressed
# we don't want to start this tedious process twice if avoidable
if [ ! -f $image.dd ]
then
  echo "uncompressing $image.gz"
  zcat $image.gz | pv -cN zcat > $image.dd
else
  echo "image $image.dd already uncompressed"
fi
# check if the vmdk file was already converted
# we don't want to start this tedious process twice if avoidable
if [ ! -f $image.vmdk ]
then
  vmware_convert $image.dd $image.vmdk
else
  echo "vmware image $image.vmdk already converted"
fi
```

Comment: for MacOS you might want to change apt-get install with sudo port install and instead of qemu-utils you need qemu then ...

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an another option, you could use https://sourceforge.net/projects/dd2vmdk/ as well. dd2vmdk is a *nix-based program that allows you to mount raw disk images (created by dd, dcfldd, dc3dd, ftk imager, etc) by taking the raw image, analyzing the master boot record (physical sector 0), and getting specific information that is need to create a vmdk file.

Personally, imo Qemu and the Zapotek's raw2vmdk tools are the best overall options to convert dd to vmdks.

Disclosure: I am the author of this project.

Comment: Judging from your username and the name of the author of that project, it seems that this is your work. Please disclose your affiliation, as otherwise this is considered spam. Read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I've used dd2vmdk and its great.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using:

dd2vmdk
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dd2vmdk/
https://github.com/labgeek/dd2vmdk

and

raw2vmdk
https://sourceforge.net/projects/raw2vmdk/
https://github.com/Zapotek/raw2vmdk

raw2vmdk works better imo, but its java.. Either way, Raw, IMG, ISO, and any uncompressed DD image will work.

it turns out vmdk files can reference other files, with the data. these type of vmdk files are created with raw2vmdk. I've easily mounted oVirt Raw disks, DD Raw Disks, ISO files like this.

This is the tpl file that is used to make the text vmdk files via raw2vmdk:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="UTF-8"
CID=fffffffe
parentCID=ffffffff
isNativeSnapshot="no"
createType="monolithicFlat"

# Extent description
RW [numOfSectors] FLAT "[imgLocation]" 0

# The Disk Data Base
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "7"
ddb.longContentID = "29075898903f9855853610dffffffffe"
ddb.uuid = "60 00 C2 91 8e 73 27 62-43 58 3b f8 05 ae 2e a0"
ddb.geometry.cylinders = "[numOfCylinders]"
ddb.geometry.heads = "[headsPerTrack]"
ddb.geometry.sectors = "[sectorsPerTrack]"
ddb.adapterType = "[diskType]"
```